# Addition between `signed int` and `unsigned int`

Tags: c++

Here is an example from "C++ Primer" which indicates that `signed int` will be automatically converted to `unsigned int` when added with `unsigned int`. But the result I got seemed to be that `unsigned int` was casted to `signed int` instead. Could anyone tell me why?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = -1;
    unsigned int u = 10;

    cout << i + u << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

9

Comment: Your result fits perfectly with the modulo behaviour of unsigned addition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a pretty uninteresting example. How can you tell if `9` is a `signed` or `unsigned int` (or `long` or `short` or ...)? It's in the range of all of these types.

Here's a better example:

```
int i = -12;
unsigned int u = 10;
cout << i + u << endl; // prints 4294967294
```

Or really:

```
static_assert(is_same<decltype(i+u), unsigned int>::value,
              "wat");
```